# where should I put my project git repository when using docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a docker with the following docker-compose.yml configuration

```
version: '2'
services:
 payments:
  build: .
  container_name: 'my-container'
  expose:
    - "80"
    - "27017"
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www/html
  read_only: false
  privileged: true
  tty: true
```

and this Dockerfile

```
FROM my-private/repo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
EXPOSE 22 80
```

In my localhost, it works as expected. However, I want to deploy my docker in a container service configured with Swarm (1 master node and 2 agents).

Where should I put the code? In my localhost, the code is mounted from "." to "/var/www/html". However after deploying to Swarm, the folder /var/www/html is empty.

Any idea? Thank you for help

Comment: It is probably more useful for swarm deployment to add the html into the image. I assume it does not change dynamically.

Comment: In such case, how would you manage your code changes? For example, I want to use the docker on development environment so I need to open my IDE, work in my code and then watch changes I made